# Load numbers from binary file represented with two bytes each

Tags: c, binary, integer, binaryfiles

How could I load numbers from binary file which are nonnegative integers in the range 0-65535 represented by two bytes each?

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
int main() {
  const char file[] = "numbers.dat";
  FILE *fp = fopen(file, "rb");
  uint16_t arr[100000];
  int i;
  int loaded=fread(arr, 2, 100000, fp);
  printf("Loaded numbers: %d\n", loaded);
  for (i = 0; i < loaded; i++)
    printf("%d ", arr[i]);
  fclose(fp);
  return 0;
}
```

If I convert numbers 12142422342 to binary it would be: 11011001010010101110010 (I convert them one by one) and run this program I get output

**Loaded numbers: 11**

**12593 12592 12337 12592 12592 12336 12337 12337 12593 12337 12592**

How could I load numbers represented by two bytes each? Could you help me fix my code?

Correct output should be: **1 2 1 4 2 4 2 2 3 4 2**

Comment: Please provide an example what content your file contains. Is it 2 decimal digits per number? Separated with spaces or not separated? One line or multiple lines?

Comment: If you can be sure that there are only digits in your file, `charToInt` could simply be `return c-'0';`. Otherwise you need a default return value which your function is missing.

Comment: Your code deals with text represenation of numbers. Your question mentions 2 byte numbers in range `0..65535`. That is only possible if you are dealing with binary data. Please clarify what data you actually need to handle.

Comment: separated by 0 .

Comment: I need to handle binary data

Comment: I added example to my question

Comment: That sample looks like text digits, not binary data. Or is this a hex dump of the input? Also it seems to be *one or two bytes* instead of *two bytes*.

Comment: sorry I'm beginner in programming, I don't understand. I have file, and output. I think that it is text digits file, but I need to load it as binary.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242623/discussion-between-gerhardh-and-codproe).

Comment: I edited my code, could you help me fix it?

Comment: @Gerhardh could you post simple answer to this? I'm suffering days on this task

Comment: BTW the string "11011001010010101110010" does not properly represent the data `1 2 1 4 2`. There is no way to tell that the first 1 should be read as a single bit, maybe the first number is really 3 or 6 or 13 or... you get the idea.

Comment: @harold how would these numbers 12142422342 look inside a binary file?

Comment: @codproe it wouldn't be printable, I could write it in hex but I'm afraid you'd misinterpret that, it would look like the file you'd get if you wrote this array to a file: `unsigned char rawData[22] = { 0x01, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x01, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x02, 0x00 };` (don't paste this in the file obviously, take this array and write a little program that writes it to a file)

Comment: @harold thank you very much, I saved it and now it loads correct numbers

Comment: Huh? Yo showed test code that creates exactly that binary file. Why are you messing around with text files again?

Comment: @Gerhardh I don't know any better way to do it. It doesn't work correctly for any autotest... It just worked for this case on my pc..

Comment: @Gerhardh it worked finally on autotests, I just don't understand why it prints 1 as 256, 2 as 512, 3 as 768, 4 as 1024....

Comment: In 16 bit values, 0x0100 == 256, 0x0200 == 512 etc.. In memory this is stored as `0x00 0x01`. This is called *little endian byte order*. If you get 256 instead of 1, you have swapped the bytes.